# Recursive to iterative when using recursive-result for other calculatons

Tags: java, loops, recursion, stack, iteration

In theory it should be possible to write every recursive method into an iterative one.

I know it's pretty easy when the recursive function is tail-recursive. For example, calculating a factorial can be done like this recursive:

```
// Recursive:
long fact(long n){
  return fact(n, 1);
}
long fact(long n, long r){
  return n==1 ?
    r
   :
    fact(n-1, r*n);
}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bY@xboNADIb3PsWvTFAIKR1JUZ@gSzMmHa7kipyCie4MVRTl2Yl7x1Kpy/n82/78@2Qmsz4dv@emM97jzRBfZ2CzwbttRudpstUD0A3c4ss0koQfp1cVAWdldBwLnKNMtyrf/unPo@L@znFdl3gNimoxVksamesyh3vkyFVf5/GzowZejGiYBjqiV8vJThxxu/@Aca1flvzegh412P6EJAkYRQ8u2qK63IJenp/0zbJ02by7eLF9MYxSnJUqHSeUraqDrJChL4IxSpdTb/Md)

or like this iterative:

```
// Iterative:
int fact(int n){
  int r = 1;
  for(; n>1; n--)
    r *= n;
  return r;
}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##RY@xbsJAEER7vmJEdY5lE1ICpqegokxSHOawFuw1ulsbRcjf7iwHiGa0M1rtmz3Z3manw3ksaxsCtpb4NgKzGTbivBXq3WIC1C1XONpSTJw4uWn4jD0KzJfRH1tvluD1XCXLkphBFz4K8GPDO@k8w9/doKBLt6@pRBBFlehbOqDRDmYnnrj6/oX1VXjS7uXQKI3dNRqTvLGxChVKptXXp2qavvi7vyCuydtO8otelZoNpdPFj0yRosnjW5TEW8NkGP8B)

This is pretty easy, because we don't use the result of the recursive method for something else, and we only have a single recursive call, where we decrease `n` by 1 ever iteration.

---

I also know you should keep a stack for most recursive to iterative conversions. For example, doing a quick-sort can be done like this recursive:

```
// Recursive:
void quicksort(int[] array, int left, int right){
  if(left >= right) return;
  int index = partition(array, left, right);
  quicksort(array, left, index-1);
  quicksort(array, index+1, right);
}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lVPLTsMwELz3K1acUiUNlIdAfSDxAVyoOEEPpnVTu4kT7E0LQvn2sn4kpaIcuNhez@7OzjiRbMsGcrnZL3JmDDwyob56AEIhVEyjQFGqiKKXOTCt2WfioLzc@cNaZOu@LQglYlsiTH3qiwXn4w4UBFDhYOivwK2rUtv2IKcEjUFObBHtcRzaUu0q8v3kHCZTz9GBBMfxuAvMjlVRO2gCst9CTe@wHiXFw8Sr8JmaY62VvbZx06NlW4qlr/nlg/Cb/GEB8qLqHBBBfht1gDwCpAVsoePcA5yfwxNf1NqILR@1I7zXYrExpcYT78FX6E@apLTukHEWgPtpuA7qfjyJWvIP4j48dWjqG/oqn35gP0pxHQbDv5IcbC0@tLL6qvotFwswyJA2p66gLy@aoRYqc9oyE1TYTxIKGlLxnQuifiegdSGg7ubrOoG7BC4TGLr1KoFbOl@44KYFLhrfZPZpyPi0rDGtiBtzFZ09KyuBL0eveAYxSPpF0hpFnj5YLpNi6ef0IvthnCL9pZ443SnNucpw3dl0inTWUv6DtOk1@28)

or like this iterative:

```
// Iterative:
void quicksort(int[] array, int left, int right){
  int[] stack = new int[1024]; // Example size, alternative an actual java.util.Stack could be used
  int i=0;
  stack[i++] = left;
  stack[i++] = right;

  while(i>0){
    right = stack[--i];
    left = stack[--i];
    if(left >= right) continue;
    int index = partition(array, left, right);
    stack[i++] = left;
    stack[i++] = index-1;
    stack[i++] = index+1;
    stack[i++] = right;
  }
}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lVM9c5tAEO31K3ZcwYAwOM7EY1meSZEiRSpNKoXiDCfp0OkgsEh2PPx2Ze8DhBNcuDlu7@3bt18U7MjmRb4/Z5I1DfxgQr3OAIRCqFiNAkWpPLLWKbC6Zi@hgWR5sped2O58TXAUcSwRltZ1rcF0MYCCACLOE/sE5tyUtQ4PxZKgBRQPmkTfIHBhibvxbLwihYel1RhAgoNgMRjNiVVen2gIhd9D3exyvnEKktBWYT1rjm2t9LO2uxkdx1LklvNfH4T9FKMWID9UQweEK7@3BqB4AxQa0ESjeQa4vobvyGuG4sjv@xR@tyLbN2WNE/PgG7S3mkrBSzrk1iDL9hRf8ZN5SeKb23ShJb49s0MlOTTiDw@BSVJURhKYApZhyyQUtB9Ri0JGKxMnK1uZwxOHtuH5ZbTL2NZjxNY0El2Rzmri2aRo381x2gnJPfEYD0M1HuRpafN530YwIScBWhKDPbr4PmWqUKiWDx46T5XzZ@JfVts10TbQMnvCO7X8A5iQw05PYME0NupC56ZetU9SZNoN6WNmfqD/0VthLdTWTHzbuCbpHxUObqza8PzFaOimrNHQ09fbEO5CuAkhMeenEL7QPTbG5x6IOxtk9dLQOkZli1FF2iiVd/VT6d3j@f0vvIJgtBhftVYTYWnztC31XTqH6LK2rtekaW6R5GqLu3nivy@66iU/INrNuvNf)

---

But I now want to convert the following recursive method into its iterative form as well:

```
// Recursive:
int f(int n){
  return n<1 ?
    0
   :
    n%2+1 + 3*f(n/2);
}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY5NDoIwFIT3nmJCYlJE@dGdQjyBG1kaFxULqcqDtAVjjGfHJ7KZycxi5rvJXq5u1/tQPKS1OEhN7wGIIhxV0Rmre7WdAZocSvFT8t@cAaNcZwiUJtiPBRD/fTtFmq@DBAE2i1JQtPZ33H94u@0uD13AOunY@kZfUfOtyJ3RVJ3OkKay08uPBzUykHqOQYwzQNmYEUdnyQ46zZI4Zg8CfzrPX9apOmw6F7Y860QdMr/PON4S3p9l9hm@)

In this case it uses the recursive result, and multiply that result by 3. I'm not entirely sure how to make this iterative as well. I tried something like this:

```
// Iterative:
int f(int n){
  int[] stack = new int[1024]; // Example size, alternative an actual java.util.Stack could be used
  int i=0;
  stack[i++] = n;
  while(i > 0){
    n = stack[--i];
    if(n < 1)
      stack[i++] = 0;
    stack[i++] = n%2+1 + 3*stack[--i];
  }
  return stack[0];
}
```

Which obviously it not going to work, since `i=1` before it enters the `while`, then it becomes 0 at `n = stack[--i]`, then 1 again at `stack[i++] = n%2+1 + ...`, and then 0 again at `3*stack[--i]`, so it stops after the first iteration, and simply returns `stack[0]`. How should I convert this recursive method above to an iterative one when I use the result of the recursive-call with other calculations (multiplying by 3 in this case)?

---

As for the reason why: I want to port this recursive method above to a stack-based language which doesn't have any functions and therefore I'll need the iterative approach (with stack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've been able to figure it out. I first need to fill the entire stack with the `n%2+1` parts, dividing 2 every iteration. And as soon as `n < 1`, I need an inner loop to calculate the result.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
// Recursive:
int f(int n){ // i.e. n=2
  int[] stack = new int[1024]; // Example size, alternative an actual java.util.Stack could be used 
  int i=0;
  while(i >= 0){
    stack[i++] = n%2+1;
    n/=2;
    if(n < 1){
      while(i > 0){
        n = 3*n + stack[--i];
      }
      return n;
    }
  }
  return -1; // It should never come here, but the method need a return-statement
}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TVK7TsNAEOz5ihESko2xYwcqgukoKGhIiVJcnA2@YJ@ju73wiPLtYX12ojT3Gu/szI43aqfSzerrWDXKObwpbfZHYDLBO1XeOr2jxytAG8Y66lcT73tUZ5TBlFPBAvqxgGNVfaGEoe/wUuTTh8Ws//jlR7XbhuD0H91BNUzWKBZqKANVsVcNNiIk86ybbB54qs43KywJ3tEKpzbQZT4Ll@9aNxRpPJfI4314wiDhQyfJotdxM02K2YiYSTk9nfU6MnhCcS67YLsgC2XCc39rkIzUaaoXszN@OJ8ssbcG5oQNyLCOWFqEWbwyXB28GdqRFZ8toSYrg1l6BteElrjuelyMq7E8lf5MLRkWzoMktPXLRle9LJZt1@kVWgkvmrPV5lPiUPbTjV76VNGO0fSXKB6ErjsbDVMVcfqpLPJc9iSJRxvzXydNs85zthVajtpM/oJYxnF9h@tAcrg6HP8B)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with something quiet similar (saw your self-answer only after)

```
int iterf(int n){

    //can also be implemented with an array. easier with list. 
    List<Integer> sum = new ArrayList<>();

    while (true) {
        if( n < 1 ) { //equivalent to if(n<1) return 0;
            sum.add(0);
            break;
        }
        //for each n, fill list with the fixed argument part: (n%2)+1
        sum.add((n%2)+1); 
        n=n/2;
    }

    //add to each list element 3 time the next element 
    //equivalent to 3*f(n/2);
    for(int i = sum.size()-2; i >=0; i--) {
        sum.set(i, sum.get(i) + (3*(sum.get(i+1))));
    }

    return sum.get(0);
}
```